# How to fetch mysql database data with the help of wp-config file in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Am developed a website with word press and my url like this **http://www.myhost/wp/**

now i want to add a webpage like **http://www.myhost/wp/guest/**

the guest folder contains an index.php file

this file is fetching some data from wordpress mysql database.

the index.php files are shown below..

```
 <?php
 $user_count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT user_login  FROM $wpdb->adc_eng_users" );
 echo "<p>User count is {$user_count}</p>";
 ?>
```

i cant get the data from database table...
how can i include the connection configuration with wp_config.php file

any body please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put below code at top of your index.php file

```
require_once( '../wp-load.php' );
```

This will include all the WP Functions and classes as well as all plugin files.

Comment: require_once( '../wp-load.php' );                        $query="SELECT `post_content`,`ID` FROM `chelsa_tower_posts` WHERE `post_type` = 'testimonial' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$array=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

echo $array['post_content'];

Comment: It should work please try following code     <?php
require_once( '../wp-load.php' ); // Make sure the file path is correct and is includded
$query="SELECT post_content,ID FROM chelsa_tower_posts WHERE post_type = 'testimonial' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1"; 
$results = $wpdb->get_results( $query, ARRAY_A );
echo '<pre>';print_r( $results );echo '</pre>';